# What do I name my queries when using Relay and dynamic routes in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, relayjs, relay

Relay enforces query naming rules when running its GraphQL compiler:

> Parse error: Error: RelayFindGraphQLTags: Operation names in graphql tags must be prefixed with the module name and end in "Mutation", "Query", or "Subscription". Got `editFormQuery` in module `Uuid`. in "pages/edit-form/[uuid].tsx"

The issue is that my Next.js page is called `src/pages/edit-form/[uuid].tsx`, which makes Relay demand that the query name starts with "Uuid". I'm going to end up with a lot of queries called "UuidQuery", which is a completely unhelpful name...

Is there any way around this so I can give my query a reasonable name?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @Sean Nope......